# Multiple textbox with same name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on asp.net website and my target platform is dot net 4.0.
I am adding a textbox dynamicaly with jquery with same name, Now i want to
get the value of each textbox separately on server side by using

```
Request("textboxName")
```

this method return a comma separated value.

But my problem is that if someone enter text with comma then it is difficult
for me to get correct value.

please see the screenshot 
[image]

in **php** it is easily manage by adding **[]** at the end of textbox name

Please suggest me how to solve this problem

Comment: just a thought, but if you want this dealt with in jQuery land you could concatenate an integer at the end of textboxName to make each  textbox unique (increment the integer for each box)?

Comment: Hi @Dan Beaulieu i know to add integer value at the end of texbox name and increment with newly added textbox.
But i want to without this increment logic on client side.

In PHP if  add array brackets at the end of textbox name then it is easily manage of server side by using array index to get the value of textbox.

Comment: you can use it like this  <input type='text' name='inp_text[1]'/>
<input type='text' name='inp_text[2]'/> then validate using jquery

Comment: Do **not** add controls with the same name. You need to name then correctly with indexers so that the collection can be bound to a model when you post back. Provide the details of your model (or is it just `IEnumerable<string>`?) and you view with the script

Comment: Hi @Stephen,@Arunprasanth
i don't want index on textbox name to identify uniquely on server side. I want array type feature like php, in php we can easily access the value with **$_POST['textboxname'][index]**

but in asp.net there is no concept for using same name request array
like Request("textboxname")("index") to get each textbox value.
it is developer headache to add control with unique name dynamically.

Comment: Developer headache? Whats so hard about one or 2 lines of code? And to access the values from `Request` is ignoring all the benefits of MVC including model binding, modelstate, client and server side validation etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to use the FormCollection.GetValues("textboxName") method. It returns an array of strings with the same number of text boxes in the form.